# Vector Displacement proving perpendicular

Tags: derivatives, vector-spaces

I am told that the length of my vector is always $r=1$, but it may vary in direction. I need to prove that r is a constant vector or that $dr/dt$ is perpendicular to $r$.

I understand that if $dr/dt = 0$ that means it is perpendicular, the book gave me me a hint to take the derivative of $r^2$

I am setting $*$ as the dot product for this problem
$$d/dr(r^2) = r*(dr/dt) + (dr/dt)*r$$

I found the solution online that the above equation results in $dr/dt$ and plugging in $r$ results in $d(1)/dr)=0$ that makes sense to me as the derivative of 1 is 0, but how did it get reduced to just $dr/dt$?

Also side question: Is it perpendicular always if $dr/dt =0$? If it is not equal to $0$ then how do I prove that it is constant?